# Running an .iso in Grub 2 (Truecrypt Recovery)

Tags: grub2, truecrypt

Backstory:
I'm trying to recover a TrueCrypt installation. I've got the TrueCrypt recovery iso - and I'm trying to add that as a GRUB entry (I can still boot into Ubuntu on that same device) or run the TrueCrypt recovery iso from a USB stick.

I have an iso file which I would like to boot from - so I've tried a couple things:
http://jmesmon.github.com/2012/01/26/TCRD.html - which suggests using memdisk{find} - but when I run the linux16 command in the grub CLI - I got a complaint about an incorrect magic value (so it's an apparently an unexpected input).

[How to boot from iso with Grub2/Burg boot loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15015/how-to-boot-from-iso-with-grub2-burg-boot-loader) - which uses a loopback - which I pointed to my .iso file - but the auto-complete doesn't show anything in the loop once it is made. (This may be terribly incorrect - not sure)

So I'm basically looking for grub commands to load a given iso.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

So the link http://jmesmon.github.com/2012/01/26/TCRD.html here was right, with a couple modifications since I was not booting off a USB but rather had control of the disks GRUB. So the entry became:
menuentry "Truecrypt Rescue" {
    linux16  /boot/memdisk iso
    initrd16 /boot/TCRD.iso
}

In my case the boot directory was in a separate partition, so it became:
menuentry "Truecrypt Rescue" {
    linux16  /memdisk iso
    initrd16 /TCRD.iso
}

I also realized that memdiskfind is not memdisk, so I had to find memdisk. The syslinux package built into Ubuntu appears not to have it,  so I downloaded syslinux from online (here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/).

I then ran 'make' from the memdisk folder (and if the command failed, installed programs needed) - this generated a memdisk file, which I copied into my boot folder - and voila!

Note: linux may work instead of linux16, and initrd instead of initrd16.